# What was John Cantius' contribution to the theory of impetus?

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, momentum

According to Wikipedia, the [theory of impetus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_impetus), which was a precursor to the modern concepts of inertia and momentum, was developed in the West by [Jean Buridan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Buridan), and further developed by [John Cantius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Cantius) (Jan Kanty in his native Polish). Cantius is a figure I'm interested in, but there does not seem to be much information on how exactly he contributed to the theory. The statement on Wikipedia is unsourced, Google Scholar does not turn up any useful results, and Google just returns a bunch of sites either copying or paraphrasing Wikipedia. So that's my question: what is his contribution to the theory, and are there any reliable sources explaining it or backing it up?

Comment: Wikipedia's source [seems to be](https://wiki.alquds.edu/?query=Polish_philosophy#Scholasticism) Tatarkiewicz's *Zarys dziejów filozofii w Polsce*. In English, there is only [brief outline](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25777138), which does not say much:"*from the very beginning at Cracow... in physics, logic and ethics, Terminism prevailed here under the dominant influence of Jan Buridan. Here Jan Kanty expounded physics in the Terminist fashion, developing the new concept of
"impulses."*"

Comment: My knowledge of Polish is zero. I spent 1.5 hours looking through non-Polish sources on Kanty (including much material in Latin) and could not find anything about supposed contributions to the theory of impetus (or physics in general). It seems possible that some previously overlooked manuscripts *attributed* to Kanty were found in the 20th century that contain such material, but I have not found any publications along those lines.